# Trouble with Identity Range Sizes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, merge-replication, identity-management

I am trying to setup our replication with a republisher.  We, unfortunately, have some tables with an int PK IDENTITY and I am getting the following error when trying to create the publication.

```
SQL Server Management Studio could not create article 'tblAdminBusinessType'. (New Publication Wizard)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

The republisher's republishing range obtained from its publisher is not large enough to allocate the specified @pub_identity_range.
The article 'tblAdminBusinessType' could not be added to the publication 'Stage_Connect'.
Changed database context to 'Stage_Connect'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 20660)
```

I changed the Publisher range size to 100000 and the Subscriber range size to 100.  What I am not understanding is why this even matters, this table is marked as download only at both the Primary Publisher and the Re-Publisher.  It can't be updated anywhere BUT directly on the Primary so what's the issue.

Secondly, how do I overcome this?  Do I just keep massaging the numbers till it works?  What, specifically, is it looking for?

Thanks

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/190650c5-9411-4a79-a5f9-7ebe014d9cfb/) - it shows you how to make educated guesses as to what the ranges need to be.